# How to make space around bar clickable in echarts bar chart?

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, echarts, apache-echarts

The 'click' event gets triggered only when clicked exactly inside the bar. This is not convenient if we have a bar with small width or height. When i hover the bar, some space around the bar is highlighted with full chart height and tooltip is displayed. i want to make the highlighted region clickable and the bar data should be available in the event. I have gone through the docs and tried
chart.on('click', 'xAxis.category', function () {...});
But the function is not triggered.

In this demo, Alert is triggered only when i click inside a bar. How do i make the surrounding area clickable?

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-banzai-6j5pg?file=/src/Chart.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's true, you cannot receive the common event when click outside bar but Echarts is mature framework and almost any events can received with low-level object `zRender`. You need to get access to `zRender` with `getZr()` and then convert coordinates of the clicked pixel to chart coordinates. After it you will have index of series datapoint and with this to fetch category will be easy.

```js
myChart.getZr().on('click', params => {
  var pointInPixel = [params.offsetX, params.offsetY];
  var pointInGrid = myChart.convertFromPixel('grid', pointInPixel);
  var category = myChart.getModel().get('xAxis')[0].data[pointInGrid[0]]
  console.log(category);
});
```

See example:

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

var option = {
  title: {
    text: 'ECharts'
  },
  tooltip: {},
  legend: {
    data: ['Label']
  },
  xAxis: {
    data: ["Category1", "Category2", "Category3", "Category4", "Category5", "Category6"]
  },
  yAxis: {},
  tooltip: {
    trigger: "axis",
    confine: true,
    enterable: true,
    axisPointer: {
      type: "shadow",
      shadowStyle: {
        color: "rgba(255,0,0, 0.5)"
      }
    },
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
    textStyle: {
      color: "#6D6D70"
    },
    extraCssText: `box-shadow:  3px 6px 14px #cccccc61;border-radius: 10px;`
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Series',
    type: 'bar',
    data: [5, 20, 36, 10, 10, 20],
    showBackground: true,
  }]
};

myChart.setOption(option);

myChart.getZr().on('click', params => {
  var pointInPixel = [params.offsetX, params.offsetY];
  var pointInGrid = myChart.convertFromPixel('grid', pointInPixel);
  var category = myChart.getModel().get('xAxis')[0].data[pointInGrid[0]]
  console.log(category);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.9.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```