# how to use zrender with vue-echarts to register clicks on bar chart

Tags: vue.js, echarts

I'm aware there is a similar question that was asked on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64643683/how-to-make-space-around-bar-clickable-in-echarts-bar-chart), but this is more specific to vue-echarts. On vue-echarts github page, they state that since version 4.1.0 Vue-Echarts supports ZRender events via zr: prefixed events. I can't really find documentation on how to implement this in vue and am not sure how to go about this. I want to register clicks when a user clicks not only on the bar, but also when they click in the space around the bar.

The following code below only registers clicks when a user clicks directly on the bar.

```
    <v-chart :options="chartOptionsBar"
             theme="infographic"
             @click="selectBar"
             :autoresize="true"
             ref="chart">
    </v-chart>
```

The linked post give the following solution for plain js, but i'm not sure how to transform this into something that vue understands. [getZr() seemingly does not work with vue](https://github.com/ecomfe/vue-echarts/issues/111).

```
myChart.getZr().on('click', params => {
  var pointInPixel = [params.offsetX, params.offsetY];
  var pointInGrid = myChart.convertFromPixel('grid', pointInPixel);
  var category = myChart.getModel().get('xAxis')[0].data[pointInGrid[0]]
  console.log(category);
});
```

I tried npm installing zrender but also get the when trying to initialize a zrender object :

```
./node_modules/zrender/lib/vml/graphic.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../graphic/text/parse' in '/node_modules/zrender/lib/vml'
```

This was a [bug](https://github.com/ecomfe/zrender/issues/676), but supposedly was fixed, so I'm not sure if this affects the solution as well. Any help would be appreciated! I currently using vue-echarts v5.0.0, zrender v5.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer of my question by digging into vue-echarts code

Looking at the following [commit](https://github.com/ecomfe/vue-echarts/commit/8d9d5ced6dae9b47a2e3b9324298735209e1675a), to use zrender events with vue-echarts format it the following way:

```
 <v-chart :options="chartOptionsBar"
             theme="infographic"
             @click="selectBar"
             @zr:click="outsideBarClick"
             :autoresize="true"
             ref="chart">
 </v-chart>
```

and in the methods :

```
outsideBarClick: function(params) {
    console.log(params)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `import` line in ./node_modules/zrender/lib/vml/graphic.js
from:

```
import * as textContain from '../graphic/text/parse';
```

to:

```
import * as textContain from '../graphic/Text';
```