# How to determine time axis value from zRender click event in apache eCharts

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

Following on from [how to use zrender with vue-echarts to register clicks on bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65937130/289057)

The example below does not work when the X-axis is of type `time`

For an x-axis of type `time` the `.data` property does not exist on the axis object.

```
chart.getZr().on('click', function(params){
  console.log(params)
  var pointInPixel = [params.offsetX, params.offsetY];
  var pointInGrid = chart.convertFromPixel('grid', pointInPixel);
  console.log(pointInGrid)
  var category = chart.getModel().get('xAxis')[0].data[pointInGrid[0]] // <-- bang!
  console.log(category)
})
```

I can get the time-continuum value (in milliseconds) but this extends over the whole canvas (not just the chart grid)

I cannot find a way to determine the following

- If the time value is actually in the chart grid ?
- What the closest dataset x-axis value is ?

Answer (score 0):

I try with my solution:

```
chart.getZr().on('click', function(params){
  var pointInPixel = [params.offsetX-GridLeft, params.offsetY];
  var width=chartEfficiency.getWidth()-GridRight-GridLeft;
          pointInPixel[0]=Math.round((pointInPixel[0]/width)*(chartEfficiency.getModel().get('xAxis')[0].data.length))-1
          var category = chartEfficiency.getModel().get('xAxis')[0].data[pointInPixel[0]]
  console.log(category)
})
```

GridLeft and GridRight are the value in option at:

```
grid: {
        width: 'auto',
        height: "auto",
        top: GridTop,
        bottom: GridBottom,
        left: GridLeft,
        right: GridRight
      },
```